# Point-in-rectangle testing

Tags: javascript

I have this matrix

```
/// as if the create a rectangle
int [][] loc = {
  {5, 15},//(x1, y1)
  {5, 30}, // (x1, y2)
  {20, 15},// (x2, y1)
  {20, 30}, // (x2, y2)
}

// this are the point that i want to check if they are in the rectangular range or not
int [] [] point = {
  {6, 16}, //(x, y)
  {3, 17}, //(x, y)
}
```

I want i method that can take the point and search if it in the loc range or not by using 
`x1<x<x2` and `y1<y<y2`

Comment: To define a rectangle, you only need 2 points (pick 2 diagonally opposite points), or 2 x values and 2 y values.

Comment: Well, an axis-aligned rectangle anyway...

Comment: Is this code javascript?

Comment: Is it homework? God, I hope it's not for production code.

Comment: Doesn't look like JavaScript. It has "int" instead of "var."

Answer (score 14):

A point (x, y) is inside a rectangle (x1,y1) - (x2, y2) if

(x1 <= x <= x2) **and** (y1 <= y <= y2)

Your code should look like this (this actually is C code, but JavaScript shouldn't be much different):

```
 x1 = loc[0][0];
 x2 = loc[2][0];
 y1 = loc[0][1];
 y2 = loc[2][1];
 for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++) {
   if ((x1 <= point[i][0]) && (point[i][0] <= x2) && 
       (y1 <= point[i][1]) && (point[i][1] <= y2)) {
     // This point is inside the rectangle - insert code here
   } else {
     // This point is not inside the rectangle - insert code here
   }
 }
```

Note that this will only work if (x1 <= x2) and (y1 <= y2), so you might perhaps make sure by using this instead the first four lines above:

```
x1 = Math.Min(loc[0][0], loc[2][0]);
x2 = Math.Max(loc[0][0], loc[2][0]);
y1 = Math.Min(loc[0][1], loc[2][1]);
y2 = Math.Max(loc[0][1], loc[2][1]);
```

Comment: schnaader;

Can you explain for me more a bout what you mean ?

Comment: JavaScript should be able to do this for you if you use Math.Min and Math.Max, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I couldn't update it but there is a typo I think. The second part of the condition should be (y1 <= point[i][1] <= y2) not (y2 <= point[i][1] <= y2)

Comment: I don't think "a < b < c" is a correct JS construct (which is too bad, because it would be cool).  I tried to use the algorithm as written and it gave false positives.  Then I just tried typing "1 <= 100 <= 50" in my Chrome console, and it said 'true'.  It's evaluating the first expression (1 <= 100) and then the second becomes 'true <= 50', which also turns up 'true'.  So alas, you have to do range checking more verbosely: (lo <= x) && (x <= hi).

Answer (score 7):

Although the question has been answered extensively, I'd like to share my piece of code because it looks more intuitive and looks more like the math I had at highschool. Just in case people look this question up because of home work :)

```
function between(min, p, max){
  result = false;

  if ( min < max ){
    if ( p > min && p < max ){
      result = true;
    }
  }

  if ( min > max ){
    if ( p > max && p < min){
      result = true
    }
  }

  if ( p == min || p == max ){
    result = true;
  }

  return result;
}

function point_in_rectagnle( x, y, left, top, right, bottom){
  result = false;

  if ( between(left,x,right) && between(top,y,bottom ) ){
    result = true;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: That's a very nice elegant solution

Answer (score 6):

The code in the question is Java or C or some other language that defines array literals with {}, but since the tag is Javascript and this shows up on Google for Javascript, here is a reasonable way to do point-rectangle intersection in JS.

```
function pointRectangleIntersection(p, r) {
    return p.x > r.x1 && p.x < r.x2 && p.y > r.y1 && p.y < r.y2;
}

var point = {x: 1, y: 2};
var rectangle = {x1: 0, x2: 10, y1: 1, y2: 7};
pointRectangleIntersection(point, rectangle);
```

As mentioned in the comments, change `>` to `>=` and/or `<` to `<=` to do an intersection which includes the rectangle boundaries.

Comment: Should really be in `p.x >= r.x1` (same for y).
And depending if your rectangles are inclusive or exclusive, the y2 _may_ need to be `<=`