# How to give hyperllink in an image using Titanium

Tags: facebook, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am looking to give a hyperlink on particular point in an image using Titanium, like Facebook does in showing images on focus of faces it is showing names.

So is there any possibility i can do this on titanium. If possible please provide some sample code of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the click event for a view, then detect if its inside a certain area, I use a circular area as an example since its the most straightforward to code, [you can use this as a guide for rectangular areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802013/point-in-rectangle-testing)

```
var clickPoint = {x : 100, y : 100};
var clickRadiusSquared = 25;

// View user clicks on
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : 200,
    height : 200,
});

view.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   // Get the X and Y coordinates of the click inside the view
   var x = e.x;
   var y = e.y;

   // Now see if it is inside the area
   var distanceSquared = Math.pow(clickPoint.x - x, 2) + Math.pow(clickPoint.y - y, 2);
   if(distanceSquared < clickRadiusSquared) {
       // Open the link or do whatever
       Titanium.Platform.openURL('http://www.yoururl.com');
   }
});
```