# What's an efficient way to find an exhaustive list of unused rectangular spaces in a two dimensions

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, geometry

Given a two dimensional canvas of a known size, is there any known or efficient algorithm for finding unused rectangular spaces within the canvas where each found rectangle spans as far as possible (aka it collides with another box or the edge of the canvas)?

For example, consider the following image

[image]

which can be represented as a collection of boxes

```
[
        {
            x: 50,
            y: 25,
            width: 150,
            height: 200
        },
        {
            x: 250, 
            y: 50,
            width: 75,
            height: 100
        },
        {
            x: 110, 
            y: 510,
            width: 750,
            height: 35
        },
        {
            x: 330, 
            y: 200,
            width: 500,
            height: 100
        },
        {
            x: 500,
            y: 0,
            width: 150,
            height: 90
        }
    ]
```

with a canvas size of 965x606, the solution should find all of the unused space that can be represented in unique rectangular shapes such as

[image]

[image]

[image]

(etc. for the rest of the available space)

Comment: There are many ways to solve, but there are an exponentially huge number of solutions for any given layout without strong constraints. This answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45685043/3877726, it designed to quickly find space for rectangles of given (random) size.

Comment: I should clarify - the rectangular spaces found should always be as large as possible - aka they continue until they hit either another box or the boundary of the canvas.

Comment: @Blindman67: "an exponentially huge number of solutions": how so ?

Comment: `I should clarify` *in your question*: Edit it!

Comment: *"...how so?"* If n is the number of existing boxes then the number of solutions (on average assuming no overlay) would grow exponentially by an exponent related to n O(2^n)

Answer (score 2):

**By brute force:**

Consider all slices between a bottom edge and an upper edge, across the whole frame. Inside the slice, find all empty columns and note if they abut a rectangle above or below. Then merge the columns in contact and output the rectangle so obtained iff it abuts twice.

[image]